# What are the origin & possible meanings of the ver- prefix?

Tags: meaning, etymology, prefix

There is not really an english counterpart to the often used german prefix "ver-", IMO. It has many functions (verbification) & meanings (e.g. *verstärken* vs. *verschollen*). Often it doesn't seem to be used like a typical prefix with its own clear meaning at all, like e.g. in-/un- for inversion.

For example:

> Es wäre vermessen, sich beim Vermessen zu vermessen

3 different meanings (thx to Hendrik for this nice aphorism)

What rules of thumb exist for interpreting/deriving meaning correctly?

Comment: DIfficult one. My favorite, with 3 different usages: _Es wäre vermessen, sich beim Vermessen zu vermessen_. (It would be impudent to make wrong measurements while surveying.)

Comment: Wer sich hier durchbeißen will: [Im Grimm steht viel drin](http://germazope.uni-trier.de/Projekte/WBB2009/DWB/wbgui_py?lemid=GV00275), unter anderem, dass "ver" aus 4 verschieden Präfixen entstanden ist.

Comment: @hendrik thx, i have a new bookmark and probably opened pandoras box :)

Comment: Who wants to read an old book: "Die Vorsilbe ver- und ihre Geschichte" von Max Leopold. Published 1907.http://openlibrary.org/books/OL7000766M/Die_Vorsilbe_ver-_und_ihre_Geschichte

Comment: @splattne how about a *kurzfassung* ;) I would set up a bounty if i could (there is no button??? do i have to wait?) as this seems really a unique feature of German language and history. Or community wiki?

Comment: More examples, inspired by the book found by splattne (pp. 4-5): _Ich habe mich bei meinem Versprechen versprochen. Aus Versehen, habe ich diesen Satz mit einem Komma versehen._

Comment: @Hauswer: You have to [wait 2 days](http://german.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) before you can put a bounty. (In my opinion, community wiki is not a good option for this question.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a most conclusive article on the etymology and usage of the prefix *"ver-"* in the 
*"[Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (nach Pfeifer)](http://Etymologisches%20W%C3%B6rterbuch%20des%20Deutschen%20%28nach%20Pfeifer%29)"*:

> **ver-** Präfix bei Verben und zugehörigen Nomina [...].
>
> Die Funktionen von *ver-* im Nhd. sind vielfältig; vor allem kennzeichnet es ein
>
> - **Beseitigen**, **Wegschaffen**, **Aufbrauchen** *(verrücken, vertreiben, verzehren)*
> - **Fort-**, **Zugrundegehen** *(verdunsten, verklingen, verschwinden)*
> - **Irreleiten**, **Fehlgehen** *(verführen, verwechseln, sich verzählen)*
> - **Ausdruck der Negation** *(verbieten, versagen)*
> - **resultativen Sinn** *(verbluten, verpacken, vertilgen)*, dient der
> - **Verstärkung** *(verschließen, versperren)*
> - **Transitivierung intransitiver Verben** *(verfolgen, verheiraten, verspotten)*
> - **Hervorbringen verbaler Ableitungen von Adjektiven und Substantiven** *(verdeutlichen, vergöttern ‘deutlich, zu einem Gott machen’, verarmen, verholzen ‘arm, zu Holz werden’)*.
>
> Die für nhd. *ver-* festzustellende Unterschiedlichkeit der Verwendungsweisen findet sich schon bei vorausgehendem ahd. *fir-*, *far-*, mhd. *ver-* und ähnlich bei asächs. *far-*, *for-*, mnd. *vor-*, mnl. nl. *ver-*, aengl. *for-*, *fer-*, engl. *for-*; sie erklärt sich aus dem Zusammenfall dreier Präfixe, die noch getrennt, wenn auch mit nicht mehr fest abzugrenzenden Bedeutungen in got. *fra-* (meist *‘fort-, weg-’*), *faίr-* und *faúr-* begegnen; zu letzterem vgl. in frühen Texten belegtes anord. *for-* mit negativem, verschlimmerndem Sinn[...].

According to this, the usage of *"ver-"* may be used when

- removing
- vanishing
- misleading
- negating
- resulting
- reinforcing

and in

- transitive formation
- verbal transformations fo adjectives and nouns

This has it's roots back to merging three similar gothic prefixes *fra-*, *fair-*, and *faúr-*. A similar etymology has the English prefix *for-* (like in *"forbidden"*).

Comment: I cannot see why "versagen" (to fail) means the negation of "sagen" (to say). Maybe the text means one of the elevated meanings of "sagen", such as "not allow", but even so I cannot see the relation. The simplest example of "opposite" (inside "negation" idea, I suppose) is kaufen/verkaufen.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: whenever we deal with a scientific etymological approach such as it was quoted here conclusions are not always obvious, especially not after the meaning of words may have changed over the centuries.

Answer (score 3):

Another common meaning of the prefix is to indicate that something went wrong.

Some examples from the top of my head:
laufen -> sich verlaufen
haspeln -> sich verhaspeln
scherzen -> es sich mit jdm. verscherzen
gießen -> vergießen

Comment: yeah thats the typical cases i head in my head. Imo the origin/meaning would get more clear on words like *verringern* where i dont see a real prefix function. As there is no pendant in english it seems unique in German.

Comment: @Hauser: No pendant, like for so many German prefixes. And it's not only "ver" that has these ambiguities. Prefixes often just give a word a completely different meaning, without any clear rule.

Comment: @hendrik how frequent is often. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/difference-between-kaufen-einkaufen-aufkaufen-and-ankaufen yield all different english pendants. So actually the prefix in German often simplifies learning of the language while in Engish you have to learn several different words for fine nuances imo. Dont you agree? ver- just seems to be the exception that proves the rule

Comment: @Hauser: (I'm not sure what you're saying with your 2nd sentence, the only containing the link). I thought of "be-", "er-" and "ent-", so it's not really _so_ many prefixes. But also supposedly clear cases such as "über-" can act surprisingly, e.g. in "überlegen".

Comment: @hendrik *überlegen, entbeinen* is a nice metaphor and meaning derivable & conclusive imo, while *vernichten, verringern* dont really give you any hints to deduce meaning. ver- still seems much more unique to me...splattne linked a whole book above in comment :)

Comment: @Hauser: You're right, "ver-" is more difficult than "ent-", but I also find "er-" quite bad.

Comment: @Hendrik *erlauben, erfinden, erschiessen* yeah also weird, but as far i looked much less er- than ver- words in german dictionary. Also the er- verbs seem to be 100% transitive...

Answer (score 2):

The "ver" prefix corresponds loosely to "for" in the English (and Scandinavian) languages.

Vergeben: to forgive.

The approximate meaning is "to cause", or "to make".

Verstärken: to make/cause to be strong; verfolgen: to cause to be "followed" (to persecute); verheiraten: to make "married", the act of marrying; vertreiben: to cause to be "driven" (to drive away).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a pretty common of the "ver-" prefix is "to increase some property".

- verstärken: give something more strength (Stärke)
- verehren: to increase someones glory (Ehre)
- veredeln: to make something more precious (edel)
- ...

Comment: imo this is the verbification example (Stärke, Ehre, edel). Counter example would be `verringern` :) Here ver- is not really a prefix as *ringern* is not derivable?

Comment: @Hauser: yes, I'm well aware that by far not all "ver-" words match this description. It's just one common use.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best explanation I could find about how 'ver' is used

ver-

bad, awry
English mis-

verachten (despise)
verbilden (miseducate)
verderben (go bad, spoil)
s. verfahren (go astray, get lost)
verkommen (go to ruin, become run down)
verschlafen (oversleep)

lose, away/out

verdrängen (drive out)
verduften (lose its aroma)
verlassen (leave, abandon)
verlieren (lose)

English for-

verbieten (forbid)
vergeben (forgive)
vergessen (forget)

To link something together or
 bind them

verbinden (bandage, link, tie)
vergrößern (enlarge)
verhaften (arrest)
versprechen (promise)

http://german.about.com/od/grammar/fl/Inseparable-German-Verb-Prefixes.htm

Comment: verstehen, vertragen, vereinbaren -- that approach is too simplistic.