# Origin and Meaning of Prefix "ver-"

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is etymology of the prefix "ver" and what does it do to a word?

For example, "lassen" means "let" but "verlassen" means "leave"

Comment: You can find etymology and meanings in a dictionary, for example [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ver-#German). In my experience the meaning of "ver"+verb is not entirely predictable from the meaning of the verb. Also, wasn't there a whole controversy last summer about using the "black-white-red" flag here?

Comment: Why do you compare *let* with *to leave* - shouldn't you show us the meaning of *lassen* to analyze *verlassen*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the origin & possible meanings of the ver- prefix?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/what-are-the-origin-possible-meanings-of-the-ver-prefix)

Answer (score 5):

Das Folgende paraphrasiert das entsprechende Lemma "ver-" im "Kluge" (Etymologisches Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache, Kluge, bearbeitet von Elmar Seebold, 25. Auflage, S. 949f) und stellt vermutlich den Stand etymologischen Wissens dar:

Die neuhochdeutsche Vorsilbe "ver-" stanmmt vom mittelhochdeutschen "ver-" bzw. dem althochdeutschen "fir-" und "far-" ab. Entsprechend (und ebenso einheitlich) gibt es im Altenglischen "for-" bzw. im Altfranzösischen "fur-" oder auch "for-".

Dahingegen gibt es noch im Gotischen, ebenso wie in anderen außergermanischen Sprachen, die drei Formen "faur", "fair-" und "fra-", die alle im Deutschen zusammenfallen zu "ver-". Ebenso außergermanisch zB. altindisch "purá", "prá" und "pári", altgriechisch "peri-", "pro-" und "para-", lateinisch "pro-" ("por-") und "per-", etc.

Vermutlich hängen diese Präfixe alle zusammen und stammen von der rekonstruierten indogermanischen Wurzel "*per-" (hinübergehen, fahren) ab.

Die unterschiedliche Bedeutung der drei zusammengefallenen Präfixe ist in den heutigen Formen kaum festzustellen:

- Für "fair-" finden sich keine klaren Entsprechungen.
- "ver-" das von "faur" abgeleitet wurde, meint stärker räumlich geprägte Ausgangspunkte ("über etwas hinaus", "an eine andere Stelle"), zB "verschlafen", "versetzen"
- zu "fra-" gehören Worte in der Bedeutung "verarbeiten", "verschwinden", "verbrauchen", aber auch für die Umkehrung der Bedeutung, wie "verlernen", "verspielen"

Insgesamt meint Seebold (der auch ein paar Literaturangaben macht, siehe unten) aber, daß der Zusammenfall schon so alt sei, daß eine solche Einteilung für die neuhochdeutsche Sprache "wenig Sinn hat".

Von Seebold angeführte Literatur:

- T. J. Johannisson, Verbal och postverbal partikelkomposition, Dissertation, Lund, 1939
- E. Öhmann, Festgabe für U. Pretzel, Berlin, 1963, S327-337
- I. Kühnold, H. Wellmann, Wortbildung Bd. 1, Das Verb, Düsseldorf, 1973
- A. L. Lloyd, R. Lühr, Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen, Bd. 3, Göttingen und Zürich, 2007
- M Philippa u.a., Etymologisch woordenboek van het Nederlands, Bd. 4, Amsterdam, 2009

Comment: The question is English. Answers in German are in another thread: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/what-are-the-origin-possible-meanings-of-the-ver-prefix?rq=1