# When to use "kaufen" vs "ankaufen"

Tags: meaning, verb

I'm confused as to when you should use the word "ankaufen" in the context of buying something. Can someone explain the distinction?

Comment: An earlier question has an answer but was closed: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/difference-between-kaufen-einkaufen-aufkaufen-and-ankaufen

Answer (score 5):

**Ankaufen** is a special case of **kaufen**. It means that you buy something with the intention to resell it or expect to draw benefits in any way from the purchase. It indicates that the story is not over after the **Ankauf**. The action of investing money is more important than the actual object, and the investment is considered temporary (even if made for a longer term).

Typische Beispiele für einen **Ankauf** sind Wertgegenstände, Wertpapiere, Immobilien und Grundstücke. Natürlich **kauft** man immer, wenn man etwas **ankauft**. Umgekehrt ist es nicht so.
Ein Auto wird vom Autohändler **angekauft** (also **gekauft**), vom Kunden (Benutzer oder Endverbraucher) wird es **gekauft** (aber nicht **angekauft**).

**Ankaufen** ist Untermenge von **kaufen** (welches das Gegenteil von **verkaufen** ist) und oft komplementär zu **einkaufen**.

Comment: Little afterthought: (Geld) **anlegen** is (phonetically) close to **ankaufen** and often what you want to do when you make an **Ankauf**. You expect to get back more than what you paid initially.

Comment: Did you mean to switch language mid-answer?

Answer (score 3):

„Kaufen“ is just the normal purchase, so whenever you buy something you say „kaufen“.

„Ankaufen“ is usually used in business environment.

If an antique shop buys old furniture to later sell it again, then you use „ankaufen“.

Another example would be the gold dealer buying nuggets from the prospectors to sell it to the jewelry makers.

As a private person you usually do not use the verb „ankaufen“ unless you plan to sell whatever you bought instead of using it yourself.

Comment: Other examples for *ankaufen* are bonds, artwork, real estate, collections and currency. At least so I gather from the wonderful DWDS usage database. Basically anything you might buy in hopes of selling later at a profit.

Answer (score 2):

**Kaufen** ist es wenn man etwas kauft , für sich, für Mutti, für Vati, oder für den Onkel, oder für die Firma.

**Ankaufen** ist es wenn man es durch Kauf erwirbt. Dan ist man selbst der neue Eigentümer.

same like acquire buy and purchase ... it is not the same

Comment: Wenn die Frage auf Englisch ist, wäre es höflich mehr als nur einen "Satz" am Ende auf Englisch zu formulieren.

Answer (score 1):

*Ankaufen* emphasizes, that the other party pays the money and you are in the seller position. It is typically combined as in a shop for used cars, which offers *An- und Verkauf* (so they don't just sell you a car, but would also make you an offer for the one you have).

*Goldankauf* as other (increasingly frequent) example: you may bring coins or jewellery to the shop and they pay you for the weight of the gold.

*Goldkauf* in contrast would just indicate a "trade with gold", but not in which direction.

Comment: Ankaufen emphasizes, that the other party pays the money and you are in the buyer position.